# About the quantum mechanical relation $\:qp-pq= \mathrm{i}\hbar I\:$

Tags: quantum-mechanics

Could I argue that the quantum mechanical relation "discovered" by Heisenberg
\begin{equation}
qp-pq= \mathrm{i}\hbar I
\tag{01}\label{01}     
\end{equation}
is the greatest scientific discovery of the 20th century and may be of all centuries till now?

Comment: Well, I think the answer largely depends on the definition of " the greatest scientific discovery." If it's a matter of human lives, the most likely option is the polio vaccine, discovered by Jonas Salk. If the issue is a fundamental change in the way of scientific thinking/method, the principle of relativity/equivalence and the quantum uncertainty principle are probably preferred options. If the issue is the starting point of a great thought (and its impact on future generations), we must go back to the time of Darwin, Newton, Bacon, Galileo, Copernicus, Thales, Aristotle and so on.

Answer (score 2):

You could argue it, but who would agree with you?  Maybe limit yourself to "greatest discovery in physics" or something.  After all, penicillin and plate tectonics are also 20th century.

Here: [top ten discoveries of the 20th century](https://historyplex.com/scientific-achievements-top-discoveries-of-20th-century) or here: [25 biggest scientific discoveries in history](https://list25.com/25-biggest-scientific-discoveries-in-history-of-mankind/) it is not even on the list.

It is number 8 at [top ten most beautiful equations in physics](https://owlcation.com/stem/Top-Ten-Beautiful-Physics-Equations)

Comment: ...and think that "8. Heisenberg's Uncertainty Principle" in your 3rd link is not even equation \eqref{01} but a consequence of it.